# Should I include type="text/javascript" in my SCRIPT tags?

Tags: javascript

I read through [Crockford's JavaScript best practise](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html), and he stated:

> There is no need to use the language or type attributes. It is the server, not the script tag, that determines the MIME type.

But I've never seen anyone omit the `type` attribute in their `<script>` tag...

Do you guys include `type`? Why (not)?

Comment: Do you have link to the best practices you are referring to?

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=www.google.com&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0

under "required attribute "TYPE" not specified"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You misunderstood what Crockford meant, he didn't say the `type` attribute is completely invalid, it's just that it's incorrect. The MIME type for JavaScript is `application/javascript` (or `application/ecmascript` I can't remember right now).

The general usage though is that is `text/javascript` which browsers will handle without any problems as that's been the *defacto* standard for a long time.

In regards to the `<script src="..."` tag it is redundant because the server determines the MIME type of the file and that is what the browser will then deal with.

He best explains it in one of his videos on YUI Theater (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/). I don't remember exactly which one he talks about this, I think it was in the advanced JavaScript series (but yeah I've watched them all a few times so they kind of blur into each other).

So if you want to write valid XHTML you need to provide something like `text/javascript` but it's not the *official* MIME type of the JavaScript language.

Comment: It's worth noting that Internet Explorer won't recognise scripts which have "application/javascript" specified for the type attribute - it only recognises "text/javascript" :-(

Comment: Which IE version(s)? The standard was only decided in like 2007 or something

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288263/why-doesnt-ie8-recognize-typeapplication-javascript-in-a-script-tag

Answer (score 8):

If the script is embedded in the page, Crockford's advice isn't relevant.

If you want to write standard-conforming HTML, then it still isn't relevant.

He's generally spot on about everything to do with JavaScript, so he's probably just giving you some background information, rather than telling you what to do.

Having followed the link, that page is showing its age a little. For example:

> `<script src=filename.js>` tags should
>   be placed as late in the body as
>   possible. This reduces the effects of
>   delays imposed by script loading on
>   other page components.

The "modern" approach is to use jQuery (or similar style) to perform processing when the document has loaded, which automatically solves that problem, allowing you to put the script tag wherever it makes logical sense.

Comment: The advice of placing SCRIPTs in the BODY as late as possible is still relevant. See http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Comment: @Gumbo: Would it still be relevant with a library like jQuery to hold off script loading until the document is fully loaded? It seems like that advice is only relevant in "oldschool" script placements, where scripts will be loaded when they are reached in the DOM.

Comment: @Gumbo - I'm not convinced it's an important issue at all. Firstly, a javascript-heavy page may not be any use until the some script has run to finish presenting it, so there's little value in it *appearing* to be ready when it isn't. Secondly, if you use an external script file, it only gets downloaded on the first visit to the page and is cached after that, so it's hardly worth worrying about the cost of downloading it.

Comment: @Earwicker, you have to load jQuery before making use of its ready event, and then you'd want to place jQuery at the end of the page. And I bet, if you're using jQuery UI, you don't actually append script nodes after the ready event, do you?

Comment: @Gumbo - this is extremely controversial, there are actually much better ways of achieving the desired result but they're technically harder

Answer (score 7):

The HTML5 spec says the default `type` is `text/javascript`... so in HTML5 you can leave this blank in all cases where you are, in fact, scripting in Javascript. See [the spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type) for more information.

In HTML4 the `type` attribute is [required](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1), so you should include it in that case if you are concerned about having "valid" HTML, obviously if Crockford is saying the attribute is not needed, there is no apparent downside to invalid HTML in this case.

Answer (score 4):

I use the `type` attribute since it's required for valid HTML. But practically, it serves no purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The type attribute is required for HTML and XHTML validation so I always write it

Answer (score 0):

I will also use type attribute because, sometimes in firefox the javascript codes are not working. By using this i solved some browser compatibility issues.