# Why doesn't IE8 recognize type="application/javascript" in a script tag?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I developed an HTML page that uses jQuery and Ajax. I had the following lines in my `<head>` tag:

```
<script language="javascript" type="application/javascript" src="script/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="application/javascript">
    function someFunction() {
        some code;
    }
</script>
    ...

  later - down in the body tag:
<a href="javascript:someFunction();">click here</a>
```

It worked perfectly in FF and Chrome, but threw an "Object Expected" in IE8 as soon as I clicked the link. Even with the Script Debugger on, it would not reach the first line of the function.
I tried switching to IE7 mode, or IE8 Compatability mode - to no avail.

I lucked out and found a question through Google where someone suggested changing the `type` in the `<script>` tag to `"text/javascript"` and now it works in all 3 browsers.

My question is: what did I do wrong? Is `"text/javascript"` better than `"application/javascript"`, or is there a better (== more correct) solution to my issue?

Comment: Thanks for all the correct answers - had to choose one. Would have marked them all as correct if I could :)

Comment: I just stumbled across this little stinker when porting a FF-only webapp to IE. WHY MUST IE BE MUST A MISERABLE BROWSER

Answer (score 22, accepted):

"text/javascript" is the only type that is supported by all three browsers. However, you don't actually need to put a type. The type attribute of a script tag will default to "text/javascript" if it is not otherwise specified. How that will affect validation, I'm not sure. But does that really matter anyway?

Comment: The validator definitely complains if you leave it off

Comment: @TimSeguine depends on the doctype. In HTML5 it's all good without the type attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is that IE doesn't support the type value of application/javascript. The RFC 4329 which recommends it obviously came after the release of IE6, I guess the MS developers didn't feel the need to even support the MIME type.

Comment: Indeed. There's some discussion about whether that should change, but obviously that would make it easy for developers to inadvertantly build sites that don't work in 60+% of the world's browsers.

Comment: Recently already a bit less than 60% of the world's browsers. Yay!

Comment: What's really odd is that that the application/javascript RFC came out in 2006, and IE8 came out in 2009.  I guess it was part of their old fracture the web strategy, but with slumping browser shares they are really going to be in it deep now.  Thank you chrome and firefox!