# Why can't I bind to a click event from a css class in IE 7-8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Why doesn't this JavaScript work in Internet Explorer 7-8? All I am trying to do is wire up the 'click' event for multiple DIVs by using jQuery to select the DIVs by class name.

It works in Firefox, Chrome, Safari. In IE, it will only work in Browser Mode: IE 9 / Document Mode: IE 9 standards". Can't get it to work in IE 7 or 8.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>IE Click Target Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="ClickTarget">Button 1</div>
    <div class="ClickTarget">Button 2</div>

    <!-- load jQuery 1.6.4 from CDN -->
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="application/javascript">
        // This works fine in all browsers except IE pre-9. 
        $(document).ready(function () {

          $(".ClickTarget").click(function () {
              alert("If you can see me, it worked!");
          });

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

- Normal disclaimers: I wouldn't HAVE to use jQuery for this example, but it illustrates a problem I am having with a larger solution that does use jQuery 1.6.4. IE is often quirky, I've had to deal with it many years, but that's life.

For some reason, maybe the impending holiday, I'm overlooking something. Any ideas why I can't register the click in IE?

Comment: Do you create your `ClickTarget` divs dynamically, or do they exist when the page is rendered?

Comment: @Dan: No need tu put a "disclamer" like that just because some people I'd rather not comment on think POJS is the only good thing and jQuery is the spawn of satan. ;)

Comment: @Cory: The click targets are there when I render the page. Otherwise I would have used '.live('click')' for 1.6.4., but good eye!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's the  `type="application/javascript"` in your `<script>` tags -

> "text/javascript" is the only type that is supported by all three
>   browsers. However, you don't actually need to put a type. The type
>   attribute of a script tag will default to "text/javascript" if it is
>   not otherwise specified. How that will affect validation, I'm not
>   sure. But does that really matter anyway?

From - [Why doesn't IE8 recognize type="application/javascript" in a script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288263/why-doesnt-ie8-recognize-type-application-javascript-in-a-script-tag)

Comment: Good catch! That did it. Fat finger autocomplete error. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `script` tag's type attribute to `text/javascript` it should work fine in all the browsers.

Answer (score 1):

As Shankar said originally, it's your script type not being "text/javascript"

I tried this JSFiddle in IE8 and worked fine for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/Nna2T/

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but comments can't format code, so just an FYI...

This:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    ...
});
```

Can be shorted to just:

```
$(function() { 
    ...
});
```

Comment: In Coffeescript you just say `$ -> ...` :)