# Javascript MIME

Tags: javascript, mime-types

I would like to know if is better to use application/javascript or application/ecmascript and if i should use application/languagename instead of text/languagename with other languages.

Comment: Supposing that `text/whatever` probably exists is a losing strategy.  If you want to use MIME, use the registered MIME type for your content.  Don't make up your own, don't guess, don't copy/paste from somebody else's code.  Go look it up.  http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Officially, IANA (keepers of the [official MIME type registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html)) lists `text/javascript` and `text/ecmascript` as obsolete (via [RFC 4329](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt)).

Of those two, it easiest to use `application/javascript`.  The use of `application/ecmascript` brings with it stricter character encoding requirements and less forgiving error handling as specified in 4329.

Practically, you *have* to use `text/javascript` if you want it to [work in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1288263/201952).

Also, my recommendation is to skip the `type` attribute of `<script>` tags entirely.  Every browser will run your JS just fine without.  (You still need to serve .js files with a HTTP `Content-Type` of `text/javascript`, though.)

Comment: My gut tells me that `text/javascript` will have the widest browser support :) For example, with obsolete browsers (like The everyone's favourite browser :) )

Answer (score 0):

Douglas has written on a number of occasions that he prefers plain script tags, with no attributes. The argument goes like this:

"This script block uses the language attribute. This was a feature that was introduced by Microsoft in order to support VBScript. Netscape then adopted it to support its own nonstandard deviations. W3C did not adopt the language attribute, favoring instead a type attribute which takes a MIME type. Unfortunately, the MIME type was not standardized, so it is sometimes "`text/javascript`" or "`application/ecmascript`" or something else.
Fortunately, all browsers will always choose JavaScript as the default programming language, so it is always best to simply write `<script>`. It is smallest, and it works on the most browsers."

Reference: [The Elements of JavaScript Style - Part 1](http://javascript.crockford.com/style1.html)

Comment: Well i don't knoe if i understand but i think you're saying that is better to use just the script tag without the type atribute.

Comment: Using just <script> with no attributes is actually fine on the most browsers and all recent browsers.

Comment: Actually, I'd be surprised if *any* browser broke because `type` was missing from `<script>`. Consider the provenance of `type`: In the beginning (1995), Netscape released JavaScript, adding the `<script>` tag. A year later, Microsoft released IE3 with JS *and* VBScript support; they added a non-standard `language` attribute to `<script>`. The W3C refused to to include `language` in the spec, opting instead to standardize on the MIME-based `type` attribute in HTML4 (1997). Granted, HTML4 says `type` is *required*, I would wager every implementation simply defaults to JS if `type` is missing.