# why so many mime types?

Tags: http, dom, mime

I was just wondering, why are there so many mime-types for a single type? Like for `javascript` mime type could be `text/javascript`or `text/x-javascript` or `application/x-javascript` or `application/javascript`. Why so?

*[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type)* defines mime types as `An Internet media type is a two-part identifier for file formats on the Internet.` So, isn't one format, say `text/javascript` isn't enough to define JavaScript files? If so why there are tons?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between application/x-javascript and text/javascript content types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664282/difference-between-application-x-javascript-and-text-javascript-content-types)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where no standard exists, or the standard is inaccessible or obscure, different people will each make up their own.  Even when there is a standard, copy / paste programming and cargo cult practices tend to make any old pre-standard monsters very hard indeed to slay.

For the record, [RFC 4329](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt) specifies `application/javascript` and `application/ecmascript` as standard, and even contains a historical overview of unofficial / ad-hoc types in relatively common use.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047439/javascript-mime for a discussion of practical implications.