# Can't get my jquery slider working with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, slider

I was trying to code my jQuery slider but I can't get the Javascript working with IE. It works with Firefox and Safari

My CSS styles:

```
<style type="text/css">
.slider {
    width:656px;
    height:390px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:30px auto;
    background-image:url(images/loading.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}

.slider1 img {
    width:656px;
    height:390px;
    display:none;

}
</style>
```

Javascript in my header:

```
<script type="application/javascript">

function Slider(){
   $(".slider #1").show("fade",500);
   $(".slider #1").delay(5500).hide("slide", {direction: 'left'},500);

   var sc=$(".slider img").size();
   var count=2;

   setInterval(function(){
        $(".slider #"+count).show("slide",{direction: 'right'},500);
        $(".slider #"+count).delay(5500).hide("slide", {direction: 'left'},500);
        if(count ==sc){
            count=1;

        }else{
        count= count + 1;
        }
    },6500);
}
</script>
```

Slider in html:

```
<body onload="Slider();">
   <div class="slider">
       <img id="1" src="img/slider1.gif" border="0" />
       <img id="2" src="img/slider2.gif" border="0" />
       <img id="3" src="img/slider3.gif" border="0" />
   </div>
</body>
```

Thanks if someone could help me

Comment: What exactly is wrong, what error do you get? What did you try to solve the issue, and why didn't it work out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288263/why-doesnt-ie8-recognize-type-application-javascript-in-a-script-tag

Comment: I'm guessing that the javascript doesn't even run, place an alert at the top of the script.

Comment: When I open IE the slider won't slide. And when your in ff or safaria you can see the animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you script tag from

```
<script type="application/javascript">
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

or

```
<script>
```