# Redeclare a variable in every file, where it is used?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, jinja2

Simplified, structure of my project in regard to JavaScript usage is as follows:

`base.html` (project's base template)

```
{% block js %}{% endblock %}
<script type="application/javascript" src="/base.js"></script>
```

`child.html` (a template, that inherits from `base.html`)

```
{% block js %}
    <script type="application/javascript">
        {# context_variable is a JSON string generated by handler #}
        specialObj = {{ context_variable|safe }};
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

`base.js` (project's main script)

```
function specialFn() {
    // something is done with specialObj here...
}

if (specialObj)
    specialFn();
```

Question is: should I redeclare `obj` in `base.js` for readability (or some other reason)?

Comment: Regarding *type="application/javascript"*, see [*Why doesn't IE8 recognize type=“application/javascript” in a script tag?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288263/why-doesnt-ie8-recognize-type-application-javascript-in-a-script-tag). Just remove it, the default is *text/javascript*, so a type attribute isn't necessary except in extremely rare cases in very old versions of IE (and maybe some other ancient, obscure browsers).

Comment: If you meant *specialObj*, it isn't declared anywhere. Depending on an assignment to create a global isn't a good strategy. Declaring it (i.e. using a [*VariableStatement*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.2)) multiple times isn't an issue, just untidy.

Comment: @RobG (on "application/javascript"): I see. Thanks.<br/>(on "specialObj") Why untidy if these declarations (with VariableStatement) are repeated in different files?

Comment: —untidy because you should try to only declare it once, of course lots of people use things like `var foo = foo || {}` in multiple places. But you can also have a "header" or "init" file in each project that does that once. If it's omitted, it shows up pretty quickly. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean `specialObj`?  You are defining it as a global variable, so it is already available to base.js.  No need to redeclare.

Comment: Hm, right, I forgot `var`. But it won't change anything, will it?

Comment: You should declare it with a `var`.  No need to redeclare in `base.js`