# Simple Hide/Expand with Javascript

Tags: javascript, hide, show-hide, expand

I have created a simple expand/hide test script:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="type/javascript"><!--
function showHide(elementid){
    if (document.getElementById(elementid).style.display == 'none'){
        document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = '';
    } else {
        document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div><a href="javascript:showHide('div_1035677');">more...</a></div>

<div id="div_1035677" style="display:none">
HIDDEN CONTENT
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I get an error message that I can't make any sense of (Object expected on line one).
I don't see any errors in the above code. :-(

Comment: Must be something else, you code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/WYPz3/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`type="type/javascript"` should be `type="text/javascript"`.

Answer (score 5):

Change `type/javascript` to `text/javascript`

Full example:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  function showHide(elementid){
    if (document.getElementById(elementid).style.display == 'none'){
      document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = '';
    } else {
      document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div><a href="javascript:showHide('div_1035677');">more...</a></div>
  <div id="div_1035677" style="display:none">
    HIDDEN CONTENT
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your mime type for script tag is wrong, it should be `text/javascript` not `type/javascript`.

Browsers will ignore script contents with unknown mime types.

In reality the `type` attribute is not required. But if you are adding it it should be `text/javascript` as it is the only value recognized by all the 3 major browsers. As as the standard goes the correct mime type for javascript is `application/javascript` but is not recognized by IE.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showHide(elementid){
        if (document.getElementById(elementid).style.display == 'none'){
            document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = '';
        } else {
            document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>
```

For further reading
[Should I include type="text/javascript" in my SCRIPT tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985408/should-i-include-typetext-javascript-in-my-script-tags)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as the others have said above, you should use text/javascript, not type/javascript. In addition, using CDATA blocks will prevent an HTML/XML validator (such as [the W3C HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/)) from marking JavaScript as incorrect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        function showHide(elementid){
            if (document.getElementById(elementid).style.display == 'none'){
                document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = '';
            } else {
                document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
        //]]>
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div><a href="javascript:showHide('div_1035677');">more...</a></div>
        <div id="div_1035677" style="display:none;">
        HIDDEN CONTENT
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've set the type to `text/javascript` and it is still not working, it's probably because the element is not loaded in the DOM. There are two ways to solve the problem:

1. Move the Javascript code under the div like this:

   ```
   <div id="div_1035677" style="display:none">
     HIDDEN CONTENT
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   ```
2. Wrap the code in an onload event handler:

   ```
   function showHide(){
     if (this.style.display == 'none'){
       this.style.display = '';
     } else {
       this.style.display = 'none';
     }
   }


   window.onload = function(){
     document.getElementById('link').onclick = showHide;
   };
   ```