# why to use "text/javascript"?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I include type=“text/javascript” in my SCRIPT tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985408/should-i-include-type-text-javascript-in-my-script-tags)
>   [Difference between <script> tag with type and <script> without type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659029/difference-between-script-tag-with-type-and-script-without-type)

This:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Hello world!");
</script>
```

And this:

```
<script>
    alert("Hello world!");
</script>
```

seem to accomplish the same thing (at least in chrome, firefox, ie), so, what is the difference? why should I put those extra 25 characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the HTML 4 specification was written, it was assumed that people would be using a variety of scripting languages (there are examples of VBscript and TCL in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html)). This required that the language used was identified by the author.

It didn't work out that way and JavaScript has well and truly won. The HTML 5 draft makes the attribute optional and JavaScript the default language (which reflects what browsers have assumed for many years).

Answer (score 1):

They are required [according to HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1) but no longer required [according to HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-script-element.html#attr-script-type)

I guess the idea was the there would be different types of scripts supported - it never got implemented and has been removed as required in HTML5