# what can go wrong with javascript if the attribute "type" is omitted?

Tags: javascript, types, tags

what can go wrong with javascript if the attribute **type** is omitted ?
In other words, what can go wrong if I use the tag `<script>` instead of `<script type="text/javascript">` ?

Comment: Here ya go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985408/should-i-include-type-text-javascript-in-my-script-tags

Comment: @limelights That question only has half the information, given that with HTML5 it _is_ omitted.

Comment: Unless you have a vbscript as the first script on the page, nothing

Comment: @GrantThomas Further reading of the links inside that post will guide the OP to his answer, in my opinion.

Comment: @limelights Links rot.

Answer (score 0):

It may be not interpreted correctly in older browsers. Nowadays this attribute is no longer required, however it might be good option to add it for older browsers.

It was covered before at SO, see [Do you need text/javascript specified in your <script> tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265202/do-you-need-text-javascript-specified-in-your-script-tags)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will go wrong.  Browsers will default to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

In html5 you can include javascript like

```
<script src="js/somejs.js"></script>
```

so, there is nothing wrong with omitting the attribute type.

But we need to follow certain standard while writing HTML code.
According to HTML version 4.01 and XHTML 1.0 we need to include type attribute.some of the old browser does not support html5 in that case type attribute is useful. if you are using HTML5 you can exclude type attribute.